# React -native: expo app crashing as soon as I scan QR code

Tags: react-native, expo

Yesterday I updated some versions due to getting an error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree -- While resolving undefined@undefined. It occurred after I ran expo install lottie-react-native. Further: After I deleted node_modules and package lock.json and installed everything again my app is now crashing as soon as I scan the QR code. I get an error message that stays for less than a second and I managed to screenshot it from the phone. I have tried npm run start --reset-cache, npm cache clean, npm cache verify but the problem persists. I am on windows.

I have expo 40.0.01 installed

ERROR message from the Expo app on android:

```
console.error: React Native version mismatch. 

JavaScript version 0.63.2
Native version: 0.61.4

Make sure that you have rebuilt your native code. 
If problem persists try clearing the Watchman (I have Windows...) 
and packager caches with `watchman watch-del-all && react-native start --reset-cache`.
```

Comment: can you show us the error, or the code related to the QR Code scan?

Comment: Hi Josh! I added additional information in the OP.